# Unable to connect to Snowflake using Sqitch

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqitch

I am using a private key authentication to connect to Snowflake and cannot connect using Sqitch.  This is working successfully when connecting directly using snowsql.

My connect string looks like this:

```
sqitch status -vvv db:snowflake://username@myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com/POC_DB?Driver=Snowflake;authenticator=SNOWFLAKE_JWT;priv_key_file=/Users/username/rsa_key.p8;priv_key_file_pwd=xxxxxx;warehouse=DEFAULT_WH;uid=username
```

Have masked real values where needed, but these are correct as same as work direct with snowsql.

Using the -vvv option I see

```
[Snowflake][DSI] (20032) Required setting 'PWD' is not present in the connection settings. (SQL-28000)
```

and

```
trace: DBI::connect('DBI', 'dbi:ODBC:Server=myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com;Port=443;Database=POC_DB;Driver=Snowflake', 'username', undef, 'HASH(0x7fed7a719230)')
```

indicating password is "undef".

The sqitch.conf in ~/.sqitch is setup as shown here https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitch-authentication/ under the don't use passwords section.

I cannot solve why it is giving me the missing PWD error, when working with snowsql?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a reference for a set up that might also achieve the connection:

- https://medium.com/hashmapinc/ci-cd-on-snowflake-using-sqitch-and-jenkins-245c6dc4c205
- Using ODBC and sqitch https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitchtutorial-snowflake/

It also looks like this error was corrected in this gitrepo issue: #439 https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/issues/439